# Google Charts Visualization Column Chart axis formatting and column colors

Tags: google-visualization

[image: chart]

I have this Column Chart using Google's Visualization Chart API tools. How would I make it so the y-axis numbers are only positive whole numbers? I've tried looking through the documentation but can't seem to find anything.

Comment: I'm having the same problem...did you get an answer to this?

Comment: All the below answers are incorrect. This isn't supported atm, and the workaround is to manipulate the min and max values so that the increment length happens to become 1 (I know that's not what you wanted to hear). [Link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-visualization-api/exndQy2JzvM/3FJ31dMaIkcJ%5B1-25%5D)

Answer (score 16):

I used the following and have not seen fractions since...

```
vAxis:{minValue:0,maxValue:5,gridlines:{count:6}}
```

The trick seems to be that with 6 gridlines and 5 as lowest 'high' value,
the halves and tenths aren't applicable anymore.

Comment: I can still get fractions with this, but I'm no longer getting an issue where the Y axis labels were being cut off like "3.0..." (these values work out nicely)

Comment: This doesn't help if my values are higher than 6.

Comment: Although this is not intuitive, it actually works fine. @Thayne this actually works even if your values are higher than 6. It sets 5 as the "minimum" maxValue, and if your data contains values higher than 5, the axis will scale up accordingly without any problems.

Answer (score 12):

This worked for me

```
vAxis: {minValue:0, format:'#'}
```

Answer (score 6):

Simply use **hAxis.format**

example :

```
hAxis: {minValue:0,format:'0'},
```

format 0 = Digit

Comment: Unfortunately this only changes the format used to display the values, non-integer values may still be displayed they will just be truncated. For example if you have a chart with vAxis data that ranges from 0-2, you will see vAxis labels 0 1 1 2 2.

Answer (score 1):

Positive numbers:

You can use vAxis.minValue to set the lowest y-axis gridline, however the actual value of the gridline will be the minimum of what you set and the lowest value in your data, so if you have 0 in your data (as it seems you do for Unsatisfactory), this value will be used for the lowest y-axis gridline.

Whole numbers:

http://groups.google.com/group/google-visualization-api/browse_thread/thread/04a001766367dc0f/84c34338c2808069 - this is an older post, but as there is nothing in the chart API documentation, it seems the functionality to specify whole numbers only is still lacking.

Because the chart defaults to 5 gridlines (this is what you'd like to be able to override), if your highest data value is 2.0 (like in the example) you could *force* whole numbers by setting `vAxis: {maxValue: 5}`, although this may not be the most elegant solution.

Comment: Better than setting `maxValue` is to set the `gridlines` option to your max value plus one.

Comment: I actually had to use `maxValue: 4` to get a decent result.  Possibly because I also have `minValue: 0`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `axisLabels` feature.
To use it, you must manually edit your axixLabels as shown here: http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image/docs/chart_params.html#axis_labels

e.g.:

```
chxt=x,y
chxp=0:|Excellent|Very Good|Fair|Unsatisfactory|1:|0|1|2
```

Greetings,

Jan

Comment: "The Image Charts portion of Google Chart Tools has been officially deprecated as of April 20, 2012."

Answer (score 0):

If you change your graph type as follow:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['linechart']});
```

will work for you..

Comment: This does work, but it switches to the older version of Google's charting library.  This may be good for some, but not if you need functionality from the newer 'corechart' library.

Answer (score 0):

```
var max=Math.max(1,10,15,20);(u have to pass the values what the values u have)
var maxvalue= max / 4;
var res=Math.floor(maxvalue);
res=res+1;
var remin= max % 4;
if(res != 0) {
    maxvalue=(res * 4);
}
else
    maxvalue= 4;
```

use the above code its working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround that I could find to this problem is that... For example, the default grid divisions are 4. You could change that number. But incase of the default (4) the vAxis.maxValue should be divisible by 4, if now increment that number so that it is.