# Google charts duplicating inexistent rows

Tags: charts, google-api, google-visualization, rows

I've a google charts loading data from json but it is duplicatin the rows and i don't know why. (see image)

My code is hosted here: http://jsfiddle.net/seinoxygen/U5Mqw/

I really can't figure why :(

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when you're actually setting the format parameter to "#", the labels are being rounded to the nearest number, so bringing duplicates.

Maybe you should change the format. I did look around for a way to configure how many labels are shown but didn't find it.

I did find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979123/google-charts-visualization-column-chart-axis-formatting-and-column-colors), which kinda dwells into your problem... but it is still not an elegant solution.